# Impossible to scroll the page to the left when the content floats in the middle of the screen

Tags: css, scrollbar

I needed the content of my website to float in the middle of the screen even when the window is resized and becomes smaller than the table carrying the content. So I wrapped the whole  into a div and used the following CSS:

```
#wrapper1 {
position:relative;
float:right;
left:-50%;
width:992; }

#wrapper2 {
position:relative;
float:right;
left:50%;
width:992; }
```

However, when the window is resized and becomes smaller than the table carrying the content of the web which now stays in the middle of the window I want to make a possibility to scroll it horizontally so that a visitor could see what is hidden on each side. The problem is that the scrollbar lets to scroll only to the right. The left side which is hidden cannot be reached. How could i fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML with what you have currently?

Comment: Here's a fiddle to start with. Add some table markup and post the updated demo in your question. http://jsfiddle.net/jksmw/

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, with your current setup (negative margins) you can't fix the issue. What you should do to center your content is using `margin: 0 auto;`

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfrnw/

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that this way the content is centered only when the window is bigger than the content table. When you resize the window and it becomes smaller than the content table, the table hits the left side of the window and stays there while the background image still keeps moving as you are resizing the window. And in my case the content table doesn't fit the background view anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but you probably should use media queries if you want to display something differently when the window is smaller than the content.